# rlike regex not handling special characters

Tags: java, regex, apache-spark

I am having difficulty in getting (java) spark's rlike method to handle special characters. Normally a simple escape `\\` or quoting with `\Q` and `\E` would be sufficient for handling special characters in the regex but they don't seem to work.

Take the example code below. It should show rows 2 & 3 as matching one of the items in `alist` ignoring case. However the code below only shows row 2 as matching.

How can I filter the rows of the dataset based on the "animal" columns match to one of the items in `alist`?

```
    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("row_id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("animal", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
    });

    Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
            Arrays.asList(
                    RowFactory.create(1, "Bat"),
                    RowFactory.create(2, "Dog"),
                    RowFactory.create(3, "Cat (Type Not Stated)"),
                    RowFactory.create(4, "Other.")
            ), schema);


    List<String> alist = Arrays.asList(
            "\\QDOG\\E",
            "\\QCat (Type Not Stated)\\E");

    dataset = dataset.filter(dataset.col("animal").rlike(
            "(?i)\\b("+String.join("|", alist)+")\\b"
    ));

    dataset.show(5, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with the `\\Q` or `\\E` pattern, but with the `\\b` word boundary pattern.

If I change your final `rlike` regexp by removing `\\b` pattern as follow:

```java
dataset = dataset.filter(dataset.col("animal").rlike(
  "(?i)("+String.join("|", alist)+")"
));
```

I get the two lines:

```
+------+---------------------+
|row_id|animal               |
+------+---------------------+
|2     |Dog                  |
|3     |Cat (Type Not Stated)|
+------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Oh so in general does that mean that special characters are not word characters, or is that exclusion just for `)`?

Comment: Special characters are not word characters. According to [java pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), word characters are `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`